# launching a pyside dialog inside of an active application window

Tags: python, qt, pyside, nuke

I'm trying to launch a dialog window inside of an active application window. The difficulty I am facing is being able to interact with the active application window once the dialog window is launched.

Here is an example of my python script:

```
class select_output_UI(QtGui.QDialog):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(select_output_UI, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # BUILD UI FROM FILE
        ui_file = QtCore.QFile("./select_output.ui")
        ui_file.open(QtCore.QFile.ReadOnly)
        self.myWidget = QtUiTools.QUiLoader().load(ui_file, self)
        ui_file.close()

        # SIGNALS
        self.myWidget.cancel_button.clicked.connect(self.cancel_button_pressed)

    def cancel_button_pressed(self):
        self.button_pressed = "CANCEL"
        self.close()

dialog = select_output_UI(QtGui.QApplication.activeWindow())
```

There are 2 options I am familiar with to launch this dialog window:

```
dialog.show()
```

This option allow's me to interact with the active application window, but this option will not wait for the dialog window to close before continuing to run whatever code is underneath.

```
dialog.exec_()
```

This option does not allow me to interact with the active application window. But what it does do is wait for the dialog window to close before continuing with the rest of the code.

Is there a way to interact with the application window while the dialog window has launch and have python wait till the dialog window is closed before continuing to read the rest of my code?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to connect your dialog's "OK" (or "proceed", "continue", etc.) button to a method or function containing the rest of the code you want to run. Chances are you'll want it to be a method, since I imagine the rest of the code will need access to some of the widget values on the dialog.

For example:

```python
class select_output_UI(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(select_output_UI, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # Load .ui file, etc...

        self.myWidget.ok_button.clicked.connect(self.do_work)
        self.myWidget.cancel_button.clicked.connect(self.reject)

    def do_work(self):
        print "I'm doing work!"
        # Do the work...
        self.accept()

dialog = select_output_UI(QtGui.QApplication.activeWindow())
dialog.show()
```

Alternatively, you could hook your "OK" and "Cancel" buttons up to `.accept()` and `.reject()`, respectively, and then attach your `do_work()` function/method to the dialog's `accepted` signal. However, if you approach it that way, your code will execute after the dialog is closed, rather than allowing you to close it when you see fit (or, say, leave it open if something goes wrong in the rest of your code).